Constructing a graph with a given Fiedler vector
Given $\boldsymbol u \in \mathbb{S}^{n-1}$, how could one construct a (weighted, connected) graph whose Fiedler vector $\lambda_{2}(D-A)$ — that is, a unit-norm eigenvector corresponding to the second-smallest eigenvalue of the unnormalized graph Laplacian — equals $\boldsymbol u$?
Well, I would suppose this is not possible for arbitrary $\boldsymbol u \in \mathbb{S}^{n-1}$; at minimum $\boldsymbol u$ should be orthogonal to $\boldsymbol 1_{n}$, i.e., should satisfy $\sum_{i}\boldsymbol u_{i}=0$. Assuming that, we could choose an orthonormal basis $(\boldsymbol v_{j})_{j=3}^{n}$ for $\text{span}^{\perp}(\boldsymbol 1_{n}, \boldsymbol u)$ and scalars $\lambda_{j}$ such that, say, $0=\lambda_{\boldsymbol 1_{n}}<\lambda_{\boldsymbol u} < \lambda_{3} \leq \lambda_{4} \leq \dots \leq \lambda_{n}<1$, then $$\widehat{L}:= \lambda_{\boldsymbol  u}\boldsymbol  u \boldsymbol  u^{\top} + \sum_{j=3}^{n} \lambda_{j} \boldsymbol  v_{j}\boldsymbol  v_{j}^{\top}$$
might do the trick. At least, I think it would do the trick if it were true that any (symmetric) positive semidefinite matrix $\boldsymbol M$ with $\boldsymbol 1_{n} \in \text{ker } \boldsymbol M$  is the (unnormalized) graph Laplacian of some weighted graph. But I am also not sure if this is true!
Thoughts appreciated.

Welcome to Math Exchange! It might help someone answer your question if you include a fully written out definition of the Fiedler vector.
